# Braintree Integration - custom form doesn't send nonce

Tags: javascript, php, forms, integration, braintree

The nonce wont show up at server side if I use the code in the documentation and I don't see any nonce hidden input being submitted. 
I've only got it working with the dropin for and could see the nonce on server side.

```
<form id="checkout" action="/checkout" method="post">
<input data-braintree-name="number" value="4111111111111111">
<input data-braintree-name="cvv" value="100">

<input data-braintree-name="expiration_date" value="10/20">

<!-- you can also split expiration date into two fields -->
<input data-braintree-name="expiration_month" value="10">
<input data-braintree-name="expiration_year" value="2020">

<input data-braintree-name="postal_code" value="94107">
<input data-braintree-name="cardholder_name" value="John Smith">

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Pay">
```

```
  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.24.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        var clientToken = null;

$.get( "/csgosupply/generateToken", function( data ) {
    clientToken = data;

    braintree.setup(clientToken, "custom", {
        container: "checkout"
    });
});
```

I got it working with this guy's code [Braintree - Custom - Manual form submission onPaymentMethodReceived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188275/braintree-custom-manual-form-submission-onpaymentmethodreceived)

I get "gateway_rejected" if I use same card number in a short period of time with tokinzeCard though.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Is it working or not? gateway_rejected on repeat card usage sounds like a rate limiting feature of the API.

Answer (score 1):

Braintree recently released new sample code here that includes a [full php example](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php_example).

You should be able to use that instead and get it working.